# Using grease pencil stroke on a object to perform a Boolean function using geonodes

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, 3d-printing

Is there a way to split an object into n parts using a grease pencil stroke such that the cut surfaces have a male-female connection point. the basic function should be:

- fast
- the cut surfaces when joined are seamless
- they have a male-female connection point at the cut surfaces'
  respective mid points
- this can be replicated for any and all objects no matter the shape or
  size

I am assuming geonodes the best way forward.

P.S. This is basically for 3D printing, I don't know if this helps in your thinking process, but thought I should mention it.

Below are images of what i want the geo node cluster to do:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry to say this, but I don't think this will be possible with *Geometry Nodes*. To be precise from my point of view: No chance.

Comment: @quellenform I've seen people use geo nodes to create trees... How do they manage that?

Comment: This is relatively easy, because there you work with curves along which you create a mesh or instantiate objects. In your case, however, it's about editing/manipulating an existing mesh. This is not a very satisfying topic for *Geometry Nodes* and the possibilities here are extremely limited.

Comment: The blue lines in the screenshots are actually *Annotations*. It is the predecessor of the *Grease Pencil* used in 2.79. -- I think the task mentioned in this question can be done with GN if you use a simple plane as a "knife" and not a Grease Pencil object. Inside the GN you can use the *Boolean Mesh* node to cut the mesh and merge it with the male/female connection objects. But this would be limited to cut the object into 2 parts, not n parts at once.